# Editing Related Tables in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, editing, table

Is it possible to edit a related table via the browser in ArcGIS Online?

The last update I heard in February was only available via ArcGIS Collector.

I was wondering if ArcGIS Online supports this process through an online web map or web mapping application.  We are currently using 10.3.1.

Comment: do you have your own arcgis server up and running? if so it is possible using FeatureServer. But just let us know if you have it and I can explain how to get it functional.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Yes, we do.  Our server has also been upgraded to 10.3.1

Comment: okay perfect! can you explain a bit about the related tables. are you using "relate" function on the shapefile? and how is the data being stored (an sde? or a shapefile?)

Comment: I have a Valves layer on our web server in a .gdb.  I also have a table that I downloaded from ESRI water solutions from the valve exercising template.  I want to use that table, with a relationship to my valves layer so our inspectors can add information about the valve to that table, but without having to use the collector app.  they would edit through a web app/web map. http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/18/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/

Comment: This is the template I downloaded from ESRI for the valves table:

Comment: http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/valve-exercising/

Comment: if you follow through the article and just cut out the last part about the Collector you can have a person Edit using the edit bar which will be enabled. (see image below that i just added)

Comment: I don't see the image you added.  can you add this again?

Comment: refresh - it should all be there now

Answer (score 2):

You are best to just follow the article [Related Tables – Exploring New Ways to use Collector for ArcGIS](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/18/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/)

the key points are you will want to create a [Relationship Class](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004t00000004000000.htm) inside of and SDE that is [registered to your server](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/register-sql-server-with-arcgis-server.htm)
[[image]]

if they do not have an ArcGIS Online Account then you can build out an app using the WebAppBuilder that has the Editor enabled.

[image]

here is a working example:

http://haldimand.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=da4443eaa5864998b20c1dff56773de8
[image]

Comment: did it end up working out?

Comment: No, I was unsuccessful. We were not able to updated a feature service from our server using the ArcGIS Online web browser or creating a custom web app builder. We will use Collector. Unfortunately, now I cant show my inspected records using symbology from my related table.